# Populate a Checkbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, null

I want to populate a checkbox field in a gridview.

I am using the `Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Inactive")) %>'` statement but the issue that I am facing is that in the database some records contain `NULL` for `Inactive`. If it encounters a 0 or 1 value it works fine but if `NULL` it throws an exception.

Kindly guide me how to populate the checkbox so that it should be unchecked even if the field is `null`.

Comment: I will suggest you to check for null when fetching data from database, and handle a action for null. Like if you are using Sql database, modify your search query as:  select Inactive= isnull(Inactive,0) from TABLENAME. If there would be null in database, it will return 0 and you need not to modify any code on frontend for populating checkbox in gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Frank Crook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82305/frank-crook)...you can handle the `null` like this:

```
Checked='<%# Eval("Inactive") != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Inactive")) : false %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the exception, but a quick workaround would be to modify the database column to be NOT NULL with a default value of 0. If you want to allow null values, you can catch the exception and mark the check box there.

Regardless, I think solving your null problem would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following will check if the value is `NULL`.

If not, `Checked` is assigned the value of `Inactive`

If it is `NULL`, `Checked` is set to `False`.

```
Checked='<%# IIF(Not IsDBNull(Eval("Inactive")), Eval("Inactive"), False) %>'
```